# C# .NET5 Web React app - Publish only for appsettings.Production.json on TEST server

Tags: c#, json, publishing

For my Web app (React + .NET5 C#) I would like to have to Publish option, where I select Configuration TEST, which automatically uploads appsettings.Staging.json to the TEST server.

[image]

Now, when I run Publish in VS Professional, the publishing upload all appsettings.* files into TEST server and it use the only appsettings.Production.json and after that, I must edit and delete unused files on the server

[image]

Is there any solution how to copy only the selected file and use the right one like:

- TEST server - appsettings.json + appsettings.Staging.json
- PROD server - appsettings.json + appsettings.Production.json

I have in launchSettings.json many config version for many machines (with different DB connection strings), but it works only for Dev machines when I am not use Publishing

[image]

---

EDIT

When I switch launch to TEST (mode Release (the second option is Debug)) (which is connect to appsettings.Staging.json) and run Publish

[image]

All files started to appsettings.* was copied to the TEST server

[image]

When I delete all files appsettings.* without Staging I got Error, files Production and Staging had same connection strings to the DB.

Application requires only appsettings.Production.json conf file

Comment: You need to actually set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable. The default if no value is specified is `Production`. The `launchsettings.json` is used by Visual Studio/Visual Studio Code to set those variables when launching a process. It doesn't affect how that process will behave when deployed. It's not a configuration file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos hi, please check my update (EDIT)

Comment: This won't have any effect on staging or production. The changes you made affect only your development machine. This has nothing to do with what gets published. Unless you set the environment variable on the staging server, the default `Production` environment will be used, reading the `appsettings.Production.json` file.

Comment: You should check (and set) the environment variable on the staging server, not the development files. Open a command prompt on that server and run `SET ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`. If the result is empty, it's assumed to be a Production environment. You'll have to set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Staging` on the System Environment Variables. You can use User env variables, but those only affect the current user. Or you could modify your testing scripts to set those env variables when they start tests

Comment: Even if you manually delete `appsettings.Production.json`, the `Staging.json` file *won't* be loaded. ASP.NET Core actually loads the `appsettings.{env}.json` file, where `env` is the name of the environment. Unless you set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONVMENT`, .NET Core will still try to load `Production.json`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you very much, now I understood, is there any way how to set this property, then use `SET ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging` ?
I set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Staging, rename appsettings.Production.json to appsettings.Staging.json, but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which works for me was simple:

[Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0) - section **Project file or publish profile**

I add to *.pubxml file (VS Publish setting file) this line:

```
<EnvironmentName>Staging</EnvironmentName>
```

---

like:

[image]